# Swift - Exercise minutes Healthkit

Tags: ios, swift, healthkit

So I have been trying to get the exercise minutes from Healthkit onto my application and store it in a variable.

But the whenever the application is opened on an Iphone connected to an apple wathc, it crashes. I have tried debugging the application, but it works fine on a simulator or my Ipod touch. This the function I am using to retrieve the exercise minutes.

```
func getExerciseTime(completion: @escaping (Double) -> Void) {
    let exerciseQuantityType = HKQuantityType.quantityType(forIdentifier: .appleExerciseTime)!

    /*
     let now = Date()
     let startOfDay = Calendar.current.startOfDay(for: now)
     let predicate = HKQuery.predicateForSamples(withStart: startOfDay, end: now, options: .strictStartDate)
     */

    var now : Date
    var startOfDay : Date
    var predicate : NSPredicate

    switch dwmValue {
    case 0:
        now = Date()
        startOfDay = Calendar.current.startOfDay(for: now)
        predicate = HKQuery.predicateForSamples(withStart: startOfDay, end: now, options: .strictStartDate)
        break
    case 1:
        now = Date()
        startOfDay = Calendar.current.startOfDay(for: Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: -60 * 60 * 24 * 7))
        predicate = HKQuery.predicateForSamples(withStart: startOfDay, end: now, options: .strictStartDate)
        break
    case 2:
        now = Date()
        let wx = -60 * 60 * 24 * 2
        startOfDay = Calendar.current.startOfDay(for: Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: TimeInterval((-60 * 60 * 24 * 7 * 4) + wx)))
        predicate = HKQuery.predicateForSamples(withStart: startOfDay, end: now, options: .strictStartDate)
        break
    default:
        now = Date()
        startOfDay = Calendar.current.startOfDay(for: now)
        predicate = HKQuery.predicateForSamples(withStart: startOfDay, end: now, options: .strictStartDate)
        break
    }

    let query = HKStatisticsQuery(quantityType: exerciseQuantityType, quantitySamplePredicate: predicate, options: .cumulativeSum ) { (_, result, error) in
        var resultCount = 0.0



        guard let result = result else {
            //log.error("Failed to fetch steps = \(error?.localizedDescription ?? "N/A")")
            completion(resultCount)

            return
        }

        if let sum = result.sumQuantity() {
            resultCount = sum.doubleValue(for: HKUnit.count())


        }

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            completion(resultCount)
            print("Exercise time : \(resultCount)")

        }
    }

    healthKitStore.execute(query)


}
```

This is the code I use in viewdidAppear to store the value from the above function in a global variable

```
 getExerciseTime(){ time in

                exerciseTime = time
            }
```

I have no idea why the application keeps crashing on the Iphone. I have tried to change the options in StatisticsQuery but nothing has worked. Please help me out here!! And I know there is no problem with healthkit authentication as it return some data on the simulator and the iPod but crashes on the Iphone that is connected to an apple watch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are summing the quantities, you are using an incompatible type (`HKUnit.count()`), you need to use a time unit.

```
resultCount = sum.doubleValue(for: HKUnit.minute())
```

Also, if you are not doing so already, you need to ask for permission to read

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    healthKitStore.requestAuthorization(toShare: nil, read: [exerciseQuantityType], completion: { (userWasShownPermissionView, error) in
        self.getExerciseTime(){ time in

            self.exerciseTime = time
        }
    })
}
```

You need to set a usage description in your plist

```
<key>NSHealthShareUsageDescription</key>
<string>Foo</string>
```

Aslo your app needs HealthKit capability set in the project target settings.